# ranger: how to disable the preview column entirely

Tags: linux, ranger

**My question:  How to turn off the preview-column (right-most column in ranger) entirely?**

I can’t use the solution `set column_ratio 1`, since I want `> 1 columns` for showing as parent directories.

In `man ranger`, I only see options to turn off preview for specific types of files (files, dirs, images), but no way to turn off the entire preview column entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `collapse_preview`:

```
set column_ratios 4,3,1
set preview_directories false
set preview_files false
set preview_images false
set collapse_preview true
```

Comment: Very cool. Thanks :)

Comment: as a note to anyone else in the future:  the column_ratios will really affect how good the file browser feels. If you want to turn off previews, try this ratio:  1,2,1 — it feels really nice. Because the files are always on the right pane, and the right pane now has the 2/3 of the width.

Answer (score 4):

While [laktak's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613065/54670) will disable the preview pane, it will leave a small gap on the right side where the preview pane used to be. To remove this gap set the following option:

```
set padding_right false
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer only expands a bit laktak's answer.

In case you want to only disable the preview column within a specific directory (for a remote directory for example to speed up navigation):

Start by creating a custom config file `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf` if not already done:

```bsh
ranger --copy-config=rc
```

And add in `rc.config`:

```
# ===================================================================
# == Local Options
# ===================================================================
# You can set local options that only affect a single directory.

# Examples:
# setlocal path=~/downloads sort mtime
setlocal path=~/path/to/dir preview_directories false
setlocal path=~/path/to/dir preview_files false
setlocal path=~/path/to/dir preview_images false
setlocal path=~/path/to/dir collapse_preview true
```